# How to convert Common Alerting Protocol (CAP) <area> to WKT

Tags: well-known-text, emergency-services

I've come across some data being sent in the CAP (http://docs.oasis-open.org/emergency/cap/v1.2/CAP-v1.2.html) format, which in turn contains an `<area>` element with either a polygon or circle definition.  I want to ultimately get this into a SQL Server geometry, but I think parsing it into WKT would facilitate that.  Are there any common algorithms already out there that deals with this CAP format geometries, or am I on my own for parsing it out?

Comment: You won't have a lot of success with circles and WKT - best path is to approximate the circle with a polygon.